# How do I hide the Notification Center menubar icon?

Tags: macos, icon, notifications, menu-bar

How do I hide the Notification Center menubar icon? Is it possible to do what was done here, for the Spotlight icon?

[How do I hide the Spotlight icon on Yosemite, but keep the Spotlight functionality?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151586/how-do-i-hide-the-spotlight-icon-on-yosemite-but-keep-the-spotlight-functionali/186849#186849)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com). This still allows the Notification Center to be opened with a keyboard shortcut or trackpad gesture—just the menu bar item is hidden.

Comment: what about without using unnecessary system resources?